# Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to reproduce, step-by-step, the instructions on this video **"Cloud Resume Challenge Sprint (Sept, 2022) - Week 4"** from youtube, https://youtu.be/wiyI0Ngn31o, on how to setup GitHub Actions with CD/CI pipeline for Backend testing with Python for SAM Deployment in AWS. I am using modified files from the GitHub repo of the YouTube video: https://github.com/CumulusCycles/CloudResumeChallenge/tree/main/Week_4

I have followed the video's instructions, step-by-step; however, when I push my mail.yml file to the GitHub repository, I get the following error message from GitHub Actions:

```
Run sam build
  

    SAM CLI now collects telemetry to better understand customer needs.

    You can OPT OUT and disable telemetry collection by setting the
    environment variable SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0 in your shell.
    Thanks for your help!

    Learn More: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-telemetry.html

Building codeuri: /home/runner/work/cloud-resume-challenge/cloud-resume-challenge/serverless-architecture-with-SAM/hello_world runtime: python3.8 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: MyLambdaFunction
Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource
Building codeuri: /home/runner/work/cloud-resume-challenge/cloud-resume-challenge/serverless-architecture-with-SAM/hello_world runtime: python3.9 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python, searched for python in following locations  : ['/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/bin/python', '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/python', '/usr/bin/python', '/bin/python', '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/python3', '/bin/python3'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.9. Do you have python for runtime: python3.9 on your PATH?
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is a copy of my **main.yml** file:

```
name: main
on: push


jobs:
  test-infra:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 2
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd serverless-architecture-with-SAM/tests
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests with pytest
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
        run: pytest

  build-and-deploy-infra:
    needs: test-infra
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v1
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - run: sam build
        working-directory: serverless-architecture-with-SAM
      - run: sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
        working-directory: serverless-architecture-with-SAM

  deploy-site:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
          args: --delete
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: justinhenson-cloud-resume-website
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          SOURCE_DIR: serverless-architecture-with-SAM/resume-site
```

I tried to add the stanza below before `- run: sam build` to my main.yml file, but I still get the same error message.

```
- uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
```

I sincerely appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice the error message:

> which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.9. Do you have
> python for runtime: python3.9 on your PATH?

Looks like it expects Python 3.9 in your System path whereas  you're running on 3.8 and it could possibly occur due to the mismatch of Python versions.

Could you upgrade it to 3.9 system wide, and try to rerun this.

Comment: I checked my template.yaml file, which I did not include in this question, and for whatever reason, I had set a python version mismatch in MyLambdaFunction and HelloWorldFunction. I set both them to python version 3.9 and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change all Runtime: python x.x in the template.yaml to the python version that the error is referencing so for me I had to change the Runtime: python3.7 to Runtime: Python 3.9.